# Coletar fração de um texto em uma coluna Pandas [Python]

Tags: python, pandas

Boa tarde!

Estou com uma dificuldade em separar o nome dos países em uma coluna tipo string (text), onde não tenho um separador em comum, não estou sabendo nem por onde começar.

Basicamente, a minha ideia era começar a contar para trás a partir de *http* e parar na primeira *vírgula* (sentido <), mas não consegui fazer. (talvez aja alguma outra forma mais inteligente de se iniciar).

```
text
    7.5 magnitude #earthquake. 92 km from Sand Point, #AK, United States https://t.co/XjKbyhjl7v
    7.0 magnitude #earthquake. 14 km from Néon Karlovásion, North Aegean, #Greece https://t.co/Mam1KkK2z7
    7.4 magnitude #earthquake. 94 km from #SandPoint, AK, #UnitedStates https://t.co/gqdJzjfyVU
    7.4 magnitude #earthquake. 94 km from #SandPoint, AK, United States https://t.co/gqdJzjfyVU
    5.7 magnitude #earthquake. 295 km from Lospalos, #LA, East Timor https://t.co/rGvz9nC2Iv
    1.7 magnitude #earthquake. 4 km from Redwood Valley, CA, #UnitedStates https://t.co/lEnnEDqrLO
    4.2 magnitude #earthquake. 92 km from La Esperanza (El Zapotal), #Chiapas, Mexico https://t.co/6SUWsNjDd1
    5.5 magnitude #earthquake. 50 km from #Oxapampa, Pasco, Peru https://t.co/Z95OMBWLsw
```

Dataframe completo no arquivo abaixo, a coluna em questão é a última:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Iz-c-iKuC2HnsMOlcwfugzCZ9r0-Wug/view?usp=sharing

---

obs:
Precisei fazer algo a nível mais fáicl para retirar os dois primeiros números que informam a magnitude do terrmoto, foi fácil usando o:

```
df['Magnitude'] = df['text'].str[:3].astype(float)
print(df.Magnitude)
```

Comment: O link para o arquivo está fechado

Comment: @Lucas compartilhei novamente, desta vez testei em uma aba anônima e está aberto, creio que vai dar certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você precisa é de uma regex do tipo:

```
'(#*[A-Z][a-z]*[\s-]*[A-Z]*[a-z]*)+\shttps'
```

Usando isso dentro de uma função:

```
def get_country(k):
    try:
        result = re.findall(r'(#*[A-Z][a-z]*[\s\-]*[A-Z]*[a-z]*)+\shttps',k)[0] #precisa do pacote re
        result = result.replace('#','')
    except:
        result = np.nan #precisa de pacote numpy as np
    return result

df ['country'] = [get_country(k) for k in df.text]

print(df.country.unique())
```

Output:

```
['United States' 'Greece' 'UnitedStates' 'East Timor' 'Antarctic Ridge'
 'Mexico' 'Peru' 'Island region' 'Switzerland' 'Islands region'
 'Shetland Islands' 'Japan' 'Indonesia' 'Philippines' 'Atlantic Ridge'
 'Alaska' 'Fiji Islands' 'New Guinea' 'Chile Rise' 'India' 'Chile'
 'Oregon' 'DominicanRepublic' 'China' 'Jan Mayen' 'Iceland'
 'Mariana Islands' 'NewZealand' 'Futuna' 'Costa Rica' 'Canada'
 'Reykjanes Ridge' 'Vanuatu' 'Tonga' 'Venezuela' 'Argentina' 'Russia'
 'Greenland Sea' 'Africa' 'Taiwan' 'Guatemala' 'Panama' 'Kuril Islands'
 'Indian Ridge' 'Puerto Rico' 'Fiji region' 'Japan region'
 'Solomon Islands' 'Bolivia' 'ElSalvador' 'Timor Leste' 'Nicaragua'
 'New Zealand' 'Bangladesh' 'Fiji' 'Virgin Islands' 'El Salvador'
 'Afghanistan' 'PuertoRico' 'Kyrgyzstan' 'Iran' 'Turkey' 'Spain'
 'Tajikistan' 'Romania' 'Islands' 'Guinea' 'Honduras' 'Banda Sea' 'Guam'
 'Easter Island' 'Turkmenistan' 'Socotra region' 'Pakistan'
 'New Caledonia' 'Ecuador' 'Colombia' 'Kermadec Islands' 'Italy'
 'SolomonIslands' 'Carlsberg Ridge' 'Dominican Republic' 'Croatia' 'CA'
 'France' 'Northern Alaska' 'Loyalty Islands' 'California' 'VirginIslands'
 'Central Alaska' 'Southeastern Alaska' 'Southern Alaska'
 'Alaska Peninsula' 'Nevada']
```

Dito isso, tem uma série de coisas que você precisa prestar atenção. Em alguns casos, parece que só tem o estado, por exemplo. Note também que incluí um `NaN` caso o regex falhe. Para checar quantos países você não capturou basta fazer `sum((df.country.isna())`

Comment: Excelente! Obrigado.
Realmente eu não iria seguir este caminho, me abriu a cabeça aqui para novas possibilidades.